# How to use family polymorphism in Scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I have a piece of code that I want to improve, because it have some defaults :

Given the following types (simplified) :

```
trait Entity
case object AEntity extends Entity
case object BEntity extends Entity
case object CEntity extends Entity

case class A
case class B
case class C
```

Here is the code :

```
  def loaderForEntity : Entity => EntityLoader[_] = {
    case EntityA => aLoader
    case EntityB => bLoader
    case EntityC => cLoader
  }

  type Location = …
  trait EntityLoader[EntityT] extends ((Location, Service) => EntityT)
  def aLoader = new EntityLoader[A] { def apply(l: Location, store: Service) = store.aForId(l.right.get) }
  def bLoader = new EntityLoader[B] { def apply(l: Location, store: Service) = store.bForId(l.right.get) }
  def cLoader = new EntityLoader[C] { def apply(l: Location, store: Service) = store.cForId(l.right.get) }
```

How to improve this code ?
How to make aware the type system of the relation between A and EntityA

Comment: It's not clear what `Entity` and it's descendants are for. Can `A`, `B`, `C`, not extend a common trait?

Comment: `Entity` is an `Enumeration` that represent all possible types of class `A`, `B`, `C`.
`A`, `B`, `C` don't extend a common trait (but it's definitely should to allow type boundary in EntityLoader). Is it a limitation in term of possible design ?